# BootstrapVue best way to vertically align content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Is there an optimal way to vertically align my content? I have 3 buttons that I'd like to align vertically.

```
        <b-container>
            <b-row>
                <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button></b-col>
                <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button></b-col>
                <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button></b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-container>
```

Comment: Are you looking to have the buttons stacked on top of each other? or are you referring to alignment with respect to the page/viewport?

Comment: @TroyMorehouse the buttons are supposed to be displayed next to each other but vertically centered in the page :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following should do the trick for you:

```html
<b-container>
  <b-row class="vh-100 text-center" align-v="center">
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button></b-col>
    <b-col><b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button></b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

The class `vh-100` sets the row height to 100% of the viewport height, and we set the prop `align-v` to `center` (centers the columns vertically in the middle of the row). Class `text-center` aligns the button in the center of the columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can align elements of a grid vertically like this:

```
<b-row class="my-1">
  <b-col sm="3" align-self="center">
    123
  </b-col>
  <b-col sm="3" align-self="center">
    456
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

The alignment can be *start*, *center* or *end*.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a way to easily align elements.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2">
    <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Create</b-button>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Search</b-button>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <b-button class="main-navigation-button" variant="primary">Edit</b-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: `<b-row>` is actually a flex container and accepts various props (or classes) for controling vertical/horizontal alignment and justifications